# How do I return a structure?

Tags: objective-c, c, struct

I have this code that does not works since user is always null. It's weird since if I debug before returning data it's ok but after returning data is always null. How can I fix this? I really appreciate any comments, suggestions, or tips....

Notes: xcode 5 iOS 7

definition of data types

```
typedef struct {
     char *locale;
} W_user;
```

.m test file

```
W_user *user;

-(void)test{
    // user is always null
    user = W_generateUserDefault();
}
```

methods

```
W_user *W_new() {
    W_user *user = malloc(sizeof(W_user));
    memset(user, 0x00, sizeof(W_user));
    return user;
    }

W_user *W_generateUserDefault() {
    W_user *user = W_new();
    user->locale = "es";
    // but here user contains data
    return user;
    }
```

Comment: typedef is spelt wrong.

Comment: Everything seems to be correct. Did you tried logging the user in test() at the end.

Comment: How do you know `user` us null there? How are you testing this?

Comment: If your code never uses the global `user`, might its assignment be optimized out?  Is `test()` ever called?  BTW: none of this code does a `return a structure`.  All the code does is return a pointer to a structure.

Comment: Is this the *exact* code that is being compiled and run?  It looks correct here, but I can imagine some code errors, e.g. `memset(&user, 0x00, sizeof(W_user));` that would cause this.  (I'm asking because if `typedef` was originally misspelled, perhaps this might not be the actual copied-and-pasted code that is being run.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `test` to this:

```
-(void)test{
    // user is always null
    W_user *user = W_generateUserDefault();
}
```

However, that's strange, because local variables hide global ones, not visa-versa.

Also, are you sure that you aren't debugging it in `release` mode? Try `NSLog` the `user` value to make sure it's `nil`.